# rotate a globe with the mouse

Tags: javascript, math, opengl-es, geometry, webgl

I can determine where on a globe the user has [clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964257/clicking-on-a-sphere).

When the user first clicks the mouse button down, I can store where they have clicked; lets call it the `pin`.

Then, as they drag the mouse around, I want to put the `pin` under the mouse cursor.

[image]

Here is some code that seems to roughly keep the `pin` under the mouse pointer, but doesn't correctly maintain the globe; it flickers and spins randomly.  Sometimes it flips the axis entirely so the globe is momentarily back-to-front.

```
function evtPos(evt) {
    if(!scene.ortho) return null;
    var x = lerp(scene.ortho[0],scene.ortho[1],evt.clientX/canvas.width),
        y = lerp(scene.ortho[3],scene.ortho[2],evt.clientY/canvas.height), // flipped
        sqrd = x*x+y*y;
    return (sqrd > 1)?
        null:
        mat4_vec3_multiply(mat4_inverse(scene.mvMatrix),[x,y,Math.sqrt(1-sqrd)]);
}

function onMouseDown(evt) {
    pin = evtPos(evt);
}

function onMouseMove(evt,keys,isMouseDown) {
    if(!isMouseDown) return;
    var pt = evtPos(evt);
    if(pin == null) pin = pt;
    if(pt == null) return;
    var d = vec3_sub(pt,pin),
        rotx = Math.atan2(d[1],d[2]),
        roty = (d[2] >= 0)?
            -Math.atan2(d[0] * Math.cos(rotx),d[2]):
            Math.atan2(d[0] * Math.cos(rotx),-d[2]),
        rotz = Math.atan2(Math.cos(rotx),Math.sin(rotx)*Math.sin(roty));
    scene.mvMatrix = mat4_multiply(scene.mvMatrix,mat4_rotation(rotx,[1,0,0]));
    scene.mvMatrix = mat4_multiply(scene.mvMatrix,mat4_rotation(roty,[0,1,0]));
    scene.mvMatrix = mat4_multiply(scene.mvMatrix,mat4_rotation(rotz,[0,0,1]));
}

function onMouseUp(evt) {
    pin = null;
}
```

Also, over time, an error seems to build up and the `pin` drifts further and further from the mouse pointer.  I presume I should somehow compute the `mvMatrix` completely rather than by lots of samll increments each event?

I want the user to be able to drag the globe around to navigate naturally.  All code to spin globes that I've found uses fixed speeds e.g. arrow keys, rather than 'pinning' the globe under a mouse pointer.  Unity has a function `Quaternion.FromToRotation(fromPos,toPos)` which seems very promising but the source is not available.

Comment: Judging by this question and you're [previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964257/clicking-on-a-sphere), it seems you're wanting StackOverflow to implement your project for you. What have you tried, and where are you stuck?

Comment: If you don't at least try you may find asking for help to be futile.

Comment: @popnoodles you just have to tell me what to try first and I'd have something to investigate and try.  Sometimes the way to even start to tackle a problem is non-obvious.  I've put in some code, but I know it to be deeply flawed and not simply amendable.

Comment: I would just suggest completely recalculating the rotation matrix at every MouseMove event -- that is, find a second `pin` and use its relative position to the first `pin` to transform, and retransform at every frame.

Answer (score 1):

One of the approaches for doing this is the [arcBall algorithm](http://run.usc.edu/cs520-s12/assign2/p245-shoemake.pdf).  There are even [JavaScript implementations](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~romwell/arcball_js/index.html) available so you don't need to roll your own.